# Complexity of finding three perfect matchings with no edge in common in a bridgeless cubic graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, perfect-matchings, sat

According to a conjecture:

> **Conjecture (Fan & Raspaud, 1994)** Every bridgeless cubic graph contains three perfect matchings with no edge in common.

Equivalent statement [here](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/intersecting_two_perfect_matchings)

Main question:

> Given a bridgeless cubic graph $G$, can one find in polynomial or subexponential
>   time three perfect matchings with no edge in common or answer no solution?

---

Partial results.

I encoded the problem in [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability).

The encoding of PM to SAT boils down to ONE-IN-K SAT with
exactly two occurrences of a variable and the inverse encoding
is possible too (there are papers on this).

To encode to SAT I work with three copies of $G$: $A,B,C$.

For each edge $e \in E(G)$ introduce three boolean variables
$A_e,B_e,C_e$ and encode perfect matchings in $A,B,C$.

For empty intersection, for all edges $e \in E(G)$ add the clauses:

$$ \lnot A_e \lor \lnot B_e \lor \lnot C_e \qquad (1) $$

Experimentally good SAT solvers solve this encoding fast.

Is there some gadget that encodes the constraints (1) as matching
problem, so the full solution of (1) and PMs in $A,B,C$
is a PM or maximum weighted matching?

I suspect such gadget doesn't exist.

Comment: The proposed gadget appears wrong. The problem is A_e shares vertices in A and choosing an $n$ edge kills more than wanted edges in $A$.